# How to simulate Moving Average with arima.sim using rgamma instead of rnorm as noise in R?

Tags: r

As in title, Is it possible to simulate moving average with `arima.sim` using `rgamma`  noise instead of `rnorm` noise? 
this is in documentation of R:

```
...: additional arguments for ‘rand.gen’.  Most usefully, the
      standard deviation of the innovations generated by ‘rnorm’
      can be specified by ‘sd’.
```

But what I need is `rgamma`. It isn't important for me to use `arima.sim` surely, any other function with my desire functionality is also helpfull for my job.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @李哲源ZheyuanLi You right it's duplicate, I couldn't find that question with search! Thanks.